# Stream collector error on filtering the custom list

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, collectors

```
List<RuleData> ruleDataList = conflictRuleIds.stream()
                .filter(conflictRuleId -> idsMap.containsKey(conflictRuleId))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is giving me the error

```
no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that String conforms to RuleData inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: RuleData lower bounds: String
```

Pricesly , i want to do is to filter the conflicRuleIds list and then check whether are in map or not.and finally collect to list

`idsMap` contains the `key->value as [string,RuleData]` and `conflictingRuleIds`
is a list of string

For each matching Ids in the map, i have to add the value for corresponding key in the map..something like .map() function

Comment: What is `conflictRuleIds` and `RuleData`  ? if it's just Id(may be string type) then you get only list of ids means list of string

Comment: ```RuleData``` is not string but ```conflictingRuleIds``` is list of string

Comment: And what is idsMap ? a map of id of `ruleData` with value `ruleData` ?

Comment: You mean `List<String> ruleDataList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `map()` to transform the data from `id` of string to `RuleData` by getting from `idsMap`.

```
List<RuleData> ruleDataList = conflictRuleIds.stream()
                .filter(conflictRuleId -> idsMap.containsKey(conflictRuleId))
                .map(conflictRuleId -> idsMap.get(conflictRuleId))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a matter of taste, but I would first iterate over the map entries and filter entries, which key is present in the list, and not start iterating over the list elements:

```
List<RuleData> ruleDataList = idsMap.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> conflictRuleIds.contains(entry.getKey()))
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If nothing else speaks against it I would use a `Set` for the `conflictRuleIds` instead of a `List`.